# Use list elements to initalise dictionary of empty lists Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

I have a list. I want to use its elements to initialise a dictionary, which `n` pairs of `key:list()`.

Current input :

`names = ['John', 'Jane', 'Mark']`

desired output after transformation :

`names_dict = {'John': list(), 'Jane': list(), 'Mark': list()}`

The easiest way I see is appending iteratively the `key:list()` pairs in a for loop.
Are there any more *pythonic* ways of doing this transformation ?

Answer (score 1):

A [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) is not much different than a `for` loop but slightly more pythonic:

```
names_dict = {name: list() for name in names}
```

Comment: I didn't know dict comprehesions were a thing. This changes a lot

Comment: Only knew about generators expression and list comprehesions. Thank you @Selcuk